# Why is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} { {nx^{n-1}} \over {1+x} }dx=1/2$?

Tags: integration, limits

The function sequence $f_n=nx^{n-1}$ tends to zero for all $x \in [0,1)$. Why is the above limit not equal to $0$? Can you show it with Lebesgue's convergence theorems?

Comment: what must you check for before applying Lebesgue's DOMINATED convergence theorem? (anyway, to calculate the integral, integration by parts is a very good idea... look at the numerator. And then check whether dominated convergence can be applied)

Comment: Put $x = t^{1/n}$ and use the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Doesn't this sequence of functions converge uniformly on $[0,1]$?

Comment: No, it does not even converge on [0,1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $nx^{n-1}$ is the derivative of $x^n$, it suggests we first integrate by parts:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\, dx = \frac{1}{2} + \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{(1+x)^2}\,dx.$$

*Now* you can use the dominated (or even just the monotone) convergence theorem to conclude that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{(1+x)^2} \, dx = 0.$$

Comment: I would suggest you also to explain why the DCT is not applicable to the original integral.